# Which is the way to repeat task in a separate thread over again cancel when the app exits?

Tags: android, alarmmanager, timertask

I need to check if no internet connection, store data and over some time check internet connection. If it exist, send data, otherwise the tasks need to repeat over again until appears internet connection. These checks need to be done when app is in foreground mode, is app is in background mode these checks could be cancelled.

I would like to know is it good idea to use `AlarmManager` or `TimerTask`?

It seems to me that `AlarmManager` is the right solution but it works even the app is in background mode.

Answer (score 1):

I would implement this as follows:

1. When you want to send your data over the network, check if there is an internet connection.

   1. if there is, send the data.
   2. if there isn't store the data somewhere.
2. Register a `BroadcastReceiver` for the [`CONNECTIVITY_ACTION`-event](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#CONNECTIVITY_ACTION). This receiver will be called, whenever *some* change in connectivity occurs.
3. When the receiver is called, check for connectivity and react accordingly.

If you want your app to only send data when it's in the foreground, you can [register](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#registerReceiver(android.content.BroadcastReceiver,%20android.content.IntentFilter)) the BroadcastReceiver when your app "get's in the foreground" and [un-register](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#unregisterReceiver(android.content.BroadcastReceiver)) it when it "get's into the background".

Determining if the app is in the foreground is the tricky part and depends on how you define it. If you define it as "a certain (set of) activity(s) is displayed", then you can register in the `onStart()` and unregister in `onStop`.

My suggestion would be to start a Service in the BoradcastReceiver to handle the sending of your data, even if the app is not in the foreground. That way you send your data as soon as possible and even if the user doesn't return to your app for some time.